# alternating chapter and section on header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use the code trying to have the header to display chapter and section alternately

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont \thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
```

but instead of displaying the headers based on the value of pages, I would like to have the header to display section first on the header after every new chapter

My template was obtained from http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

How can I do it? Any code provided would be much appreciated

Comment: You're getting the chapter titles, I believe. Can you add a minimal preamble, to show the options you're using with the class?

Comment: The section mark is obtained with `\rightmark`, while your code only uses `\leftmark`. Also, note that the above code seem to be made for `twosided` output (`\documentclass[twoside]{...}`): `RO` means "right on odd-numbered pages, `LE` left on even-numbered pages, `LO` left on odd-numbered pages and `RE` right on even-numbered pages.

Comment: @Xavier how can I change the code for onesided output? I just realised that the document is defined for onesided output.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. The [fancyhdr manual](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) gives a lot of examples with code. Also, if you want to alternate page styles, you should use `twoside` as a class option, because that it really what you are designing (even if you don't print as a two-sided document)! Without it, you will basically try to hack yourself a two-sided output based on a one-sided class, with extra bugs (ever thought on how to handle new chapter pages for example?)...